# Oracle Synonyms issue

Tags: sql, oracle, synonym, ora-00933, ora-06550

My Scenario:

- **Schema name**: schema1
- **Package name**: pkg_system
- **procedure name**: proc1

Now I am trying to create a synonyms for my proc1 as below

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM call_proc FOR schema1.pkg_system.proc1;
```

...but it gave me syntax error.

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

I changed the code as below:

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM call_proc FOR pkg_system.proc1;
```

I can successfully create the synonyms but when I tried to execute the stored procedure via the synonym:

```
EXEC call_proc
```

...got the following error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier call_proc must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

And I used the schema name to call the procedure like `schema1.call_Proc` still got the same error.

What I did wrong here?

Comment: Isn't it `CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM` (singular)?

Comment: sorry put it wrong. Change it to singular now.

Comment: I'll never understand why people "type" code questions for non-working code.

Comment: Change the question to show the exact oracle error I got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to get around this limitation, assuming you really need to call the procedure with a single name (for whatever reason), you could wrap it in a schema-level procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE schema1.proc1 IS
BEGIN
   pkg_system.proc1;
END;

CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM proc1 FOR schema1.proc1;
```

Answer (score 4):

Note [here](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/statements_7001.htm)

**Restriction on the FOR Clause**
The schema object cannot be contained in a package.

In other words, you can't create a synonym for a package procedure.

I've seen solutions where a wrapper procedure (non packaged) is created and a public synonym created for that.

Comment: If you do a select * from dba_synonyms where synonym_name = 'FRED'; you will see that CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM call_proc FOR pkg_system.proc1; creates a synonym for the object "PROC1" in the schema PKG_SYSTEM (even if there is no user/schema of that name).

Comment: I'm still not sold on why you need a synonym. Why not just have a wrapper procedure referencing the proper schema?